# Google Developers Console - Missing custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, console

I had two custom domains on my setup. Now one is not there, the domain in question, www.emlakair.com is still working and pointing to the app engine code, but missing from the developers console. The other domain is www.catchamove.com. This is working also and visible under custom domains.

I have not done anything with the custom domains since they have been working so no changes on my part there. However, I have recently setup an account on with Google's search console and both the same domains are listing on there. My domain settings remain unchanged since verification of the domain first time around and everything seems fine that end.

Does anyone have a clue, I could try to re-verify the missing domain but that will mean changing the CNAME record and that will take the domain down for a while.

Here is the CNAME record data:
[image]

Can anyone from Google or anyone else for that matter explain this or provide a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just had to re-verify again. But why? It would be nice to get some answers as to why a custom domain falls of the face of the map without explanation, yet still manages to point to the app engine project code no problem?

However, there is one anomaly still remaining and that is the other custom domain www.catchamove.com is showing A and AAA records on the developers console, but www.catchamove.com is setup with a CNAME record on my DNS management system, but it is working at the moment.